# Google Apps Script: strange "Missing ; before statement." error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I'm writing a simple script to scrap some reporting numbers. I'm getting the error message "Missing ; before statement.", which doesn't seem to be an accurate description of the issue at hand.

I've tried omitting pieces of the code but the error message seems fairly stochastic. I'm suspecting some issue with some of the classes I'm using, but I'm out of ideas.

Here is my code:

```
function getStats() {
  var stats = {'id': '',
               'impressions': 0,
               'clicks': 0,
               'conversions': 0,
               'cpa': 0,
               'cost': 0},
      campaignIterator = AdWordsApp.campaigns().get(),
      campaign,
      campaignstats;

  Logger.log('Fetching stats for last 7 days.');

  while (campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
    var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
    var campaignstats = campaign.getStatsFor('LAST_7_DAYS');
    var stats['impressions'] = stats['impressions'] + campaignstats.getImpressions();
    var stats['clicks'] = stats['clicks'] + campaignstats.getClicks();
    var stats['conversions'] = stats['conversions'] + campaignstats.getConversions();
    var stats['cost'] = stats['cost'] + campaignstats.getCost();
  }

  var stats['cpa'] = stats['cost']/stats['conversion'];
}

function main() {
  getStats();
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Run your code through a linter: e.g. http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: On which line does the error pop up?

Comment: No mention of the line, unfortunately. It's an in-browser IDE with limited functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `var` statement from each line within the `while` loop, and from the statement after it.

Aside from the fact that all of those variables are already defined (though redeclaring the same variable doesn't cause an error), you've got syntax errors because you can't include square brackets in variable declarations like this:

```
var stats['impressions'] = ...
```

Try this:

```
while (campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
  campaign = campaignIterator.next();
  campaignstats = campaign.getStatsFor('LAST_7_DAYS');
  stats['impressions'] += campaignstats.getImpressions();
  stats['clicks'] += campaignstats.getClicks();
  stats['conversions'] += campaignstats.getConversions();
  stats['cost'] += campaignstats.getCost();
}

stats['cpa'] = stats['cost']/stats['conversion'];
```

Note also that I took the liberty of introducing the [`+=` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FAssignment_Operators). The following two statements are equivalent, but the latter is less to type and (arguably) easier to read:

```
x[y] = x[y] + z;
x[y] += z;
```

Comment: @UstavGupta - I don't know, but `var stats` would be a valid line on its own, and starting a line with a square bracket is also valid, so maybe it wants a semicolon at that point to separate the two and fix the immediate problem. Of course that would then lead to a different error on the same line, but the interpreter/compiler can't read your mind to guess what you were actually trying to do there. And normally it will report the line number of the error so at least you know where to look.